# php form with exec, file_get_contents and explode

Tags: php, forms, exec, file-get-contents, trim

The purpose of this form is to update a file on my server and have the updated changes reflected on the form itself after they are made. Here is the current code I have with help from a few users:

```
<?php
    $file = "/var/www/html/colors/color.choices";
    $contents = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $color = explode("=", $contents[0]);
    $size = explode("=", $contents[1]);
    $shape = explode("=", $contents[2]);

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['color_choice'])){
        exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/color=.*/color='.$_REQUEST['color_choice'].'/g')." /var/www/html/colors/color.choices");
        echo 'File color choice has been updated';
    }
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['size_choice'])){
        exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/size=.*/size='.$_REQUEST['size_choice'].'/g')." /var/www/html/colors/color.choices");
        echo 'File size choice has been updated';
    }
    if(!empty($_REQUEST['shape_choice'])){
    exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/shape=.*/shape='.$_REQUEST['shape_choice'].'/g')." /var/www/html/colors/color.choices");
    echo 'File shape choice has been updated';
    }

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="color_choice">;
        <option value="red" <?php if($color[1] == 'red'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>red</option>;
        <option value="black" <?php if($color[1] == 'black'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>black</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="size_choice">;
        <option value="large" <?php if($size[1] == 'large'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>large</option>;
        <option value="small" <?php if($size[1] == 'small'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>small</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="shape_choice">;
        <option value="round" <?php if($shape[1] == 'round'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>round</option>;
        <option value="square" <?php if($shape[1] == 'square'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>square</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Update: I've adjusted the code and seem to almost have it working. The last option now always works as intended. So in this case on the form the "shape" value now works perfectly. However the "color" and "size" choices do update the color.choices file but the update is not reflected on the form itself. Why is it that the last option works on the form now but the first two do not?

Comment: This line `$color = explode("=", trim($current));` will only work effectively on one line. If you add new options to your file you'll need to break out each line before exploding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this. I'll give you two options.

**1st option** is to use `file()`;

```
<?php
    $file = "/var/www/html/colors/color.choices";
    $contents = file($file, FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $color = explode("=", $contents[0]);

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['color_choice'])){
        exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/color=.*/color='.$_REQUEST['color_choice'].'/g')." /var/www/html/colors/color.choices");
        echo 'File color choice has been updated';
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="color_choice">;
        <option value="red" <?php if($color[1] == 'red'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>red</option>;
        <option value="blue" <?php if($color[1] == 'blue'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>blue</option>;
        <option value="black" <?php if($color[1] == 'black'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>black</option>;
        <option value="orange" <?php if($color[1] == 'orange'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>orange</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

So if your color.choices file has these options below. Then your array will start at 0,1,2 as I used above for your colors e.g. `$contents[0]` would be the colors line. `$content[1]` would be the shape line. etc. And then you would still have to explode them into a new var.

```
color=blue
shape=round
size=large
```

**2nd option** (**Recommended**) you can do this.

What I would do is make it an ini file. You are already using the file in the form of an ini so why not make it easier to work with the values?

Rename `color.choices` to `color_choices.ini`

Then your code will be like this.

```
<?php
    $attr = parse_ini_file("/var/www/html/colors/color_choices.ini");
    $color = $attr["color"];
    $size = $attr["size"];
    $shape = $attr["shape"];

    if(!empty($_REQUEST['color_choice'])){
        exec('sed -i '.escapeshellarg('s/color=.*/color='.$_REQUEST['color_choice'].'/g')." /var/www/html/colors/color_choices.ini");
        echo 'File color choice has been updated';
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="color_choice">;
        <option value="red" <?php if($color == 'red'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>red</option>;
        <option value="blue" <?php if($color == 'blue'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>blue</option>;
        <option value="black" <?php if($color == 'black'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>black</option>;
        <option value="orange" <?php if($color == 'orange'){?>selected="selected"<?php }?>>orange</option>;
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Now inside color_choices.ini will look like this.

```
[attributes]
color=blue
shape=round
size=large
```

Using an ini file is better because then you can use the `key` name without having to know what order they are in the file. Once parsed, it's already in the form of an array so you can just call `$attr["color"]` or `$attr["shape"]` etc and it doesn't matter what order they are in the color_choice.ini file. You can add as many attributes as you want. Notice also the form variable changes as well for `$color`.

e.g.

```
echo $attr["size"]; //value will be large
```

Comment: Thanks again for the help Pjack! I updated my original post to the code I have come up with for two options. It now changes both of them but I am back to the issue where the form does not display the value that it has set in the file. (I'll have to go with Option 1 above for this. That is good to know about the ini file though)

Comment: did you make sure the form showed `$color` and not `$color[1]` when you tried option two? That should work with no problem.

Comment: Ok well if either one helps, fell free to upvote and accept the answer. :)

Comment: I'm pretty much stuck with option 1 as my file can't be a .ini file. I'll keep reading though, I think your first option is very close to working.

Comment: I guess I need 3 more rep to upvote. I'll go ahead and accept the answer as this was very helpful again :)